# Django inclusion_tag issue

Tags: python, django

I try to create simplest include tag with inclusion_tag.

```
\main
    \templatetags
        \tegs_test.py
        \__init__.py
```

Python tegs_test.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('test.html')
def test_something():
    return {'test_list':[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

Template test.html:

```
{% load tegs_test %}
{% test_something %}

{% for i in test_list %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

End I register main in setting.INSTALLED_APPS.
when I try to open test.html getting error:

**Caught RuntimeError while rendering: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object**

Please, help to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: test_someting calls the test.html template which again calls test_something and so on... you need to point at a different template or you are getting tags/filters confused.

Comment: @JamesO you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{% test_something %}` calls the template `test.html`, which again calls `{% test_something %}` and so on...

You need to point to a different template withing your tag or use a filter instead.